# MovieClip won't change frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I got a code for a wall in a game which is going to change frame if it's HP for every 25% of it's health - e.g at 75%.

Here's the code for the wall:

```
protected function checkFrame()
        {
            if (Math.abs(this.currentDamageCounter) >= this.healthPrFrame)
            {
                if (this.currentDamageCounter > 0)
                {
                    trace("Working");
                    nextFrame();
                    this.dispatchEvent(new HeatShockEvent(HeatShockEvent.DATA_OUT));
                    this.currentDamageCounter -=  this.healthPrFrame;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.prevFrame();
                    this.currentDamageCounter +=  this.healthPrFrame;
                }
                checkFrame();
            }
        }
```

"Working" IS traced.

Also, if I go to, let's say, frame 2 in the Constructor:

```
    public function Wall()
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
    }
```

This WILL work!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is "nextFrame()" ??

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#nextFrame()

Comment: what is currentDamageCounter, what is healtPrFrame? Also, i dont see any percentages anywhere. I think you would want to store it's max-health, its current health, and calculate the percentage. Then do stuff on different percentages